# Close loading overlay with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Following is the `Twitter Bootstrap` snippet which I am trying to close from javascript after 5 second but I was unable to do that. Kindly let me know how can I close it.
Currently its closing when a user clicks on  this button:

`<button type="button" class="close" style="float: none;" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>`

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/centered-processing-modal

```
<!-- Static Modal -->
<div class="modal modal-static fade" id="processing-modal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <img src="http://www.travislayne.com/images/loading.gif" class="icon" />
                    <h4>Processing... <button type="button" class="close" style="float: none;" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.modal-static { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50% !important; 
    left: 50% !important; 
    margin-top: -100px;  
    margin-left: -100px; 
    overflow: visible !important;
}
.modal-static,
.modal-static .modal-dialog,
.modal-static .modal-content {
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px; 
}
.modal-static .modal-dialog,
.modal-static .modal-content {
    padding: 0 !important; 
    margin: 0 !important;
}
.modal-static .modal-content .icon {
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to use to get it to close after 5 seconds?  `setTimeout()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without wanting to read the docs for you, here's the quick and dirty solution for the one in the link.

```
setTimeout(

    function(){
        $('#processing-modal button.close').click();
    },
    5000

);
```

If you want more granular control, you'll have to read the docs. This is intended to finish when some data process that it's bound to somehow is finished. That's probably somehow tied to a custom attribute and triggering an event or something.